# How can I inspect the value of a Custom Field in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm using an "Advanced Filter" in my google-analytics profile to concatenate parts of two different fields together and place that value into Custom Field 1:

[image: advanced filter]

Is there a way to inspect the value of Custom Field 1 so I can test that the field extractions are working?

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't found a way to view the value of a custom field directly, if you are just interested in testing that your field extractions are working correctly and/or that your regex values are correct, instead of outputting the value to a custom field, you can temporarily output the value to something that IS visible from the google-analytics UI, such as Request URI. Then change it back to a custom field later after it's been verified that everything else is correct.

Also, be aware that changes to profile filters can sometimes take a while to start showing up in the UI (see https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1638635?hl=en).

Though, if someone does know of a way to view the value of a custom field directly, that would be even better.